# 1 frame consist of left and right in audio?

Tags: audio, frame, wav, representation, sampling

In anime, does frame means number of scene per second? Each scene can consist of several layer background, hero, object, etc.  I think this is the reason why I am confused.

In wave (raw audio) file,

1. Does one frame contain data for one side (left or right) only?
2. Does bit sampling precision refer to a single side/channel?
3. With audio, do frames represent changes in loudness?
4. One frame can consist of left and right?

I.e. stereo 8 bit sampling depth => 1 frame => 2 bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know whether a formal definition of a frame exists, but when referring to an audio  frame we usually mean a single time sample of a number of channels. So 2 audio channels @ 8 bits per channel results in 2 bytes per frame. 4 channels @ 16 bit per sample is 8 bytes.